# How do you migrate to Jetpack Compose when you have a lot of Fragments?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I would like to migrate to Jetpack Compose, but I don't know where to begin. My app uses single Activity / multiple Fragments, and there at least 100 Fragments.  The app's navigation graph is in XML, which I understand does not support Composables.

Please let me know if this sounds like the correct path.

1. Modify each Fragment so that it hosts a single ComposeView that will contain the screen's UI
2. Once completed, convert each Fragment to a Composable
3. Replace the navigation graph with Jetpack Compose navigation

Once this is done, there will be no Fragments in the app.  Not sure what to do with my Activity. Should that be replaced as well?

This will take forever, but I just wanted to make sure there is no other alternative. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you read [Chris Banes blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/jetpack-compose-before-and-after-8b43ba0b7d4f) about how he approached the problem to his open source demo app "TiVi".

Comment: One activity is necessary, possibily switch from AppCompatActivity to ComponentActivity. Anyway the 100 fragments should translate in much less Composables, because of the higher reusability factor

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the Blog post I linked in the comment (which has useful other links in the matter), there are multiple ways to approach this.

What you described is a valid approach.

Now as for:

> Not sure what to do with my Activity. Should that be replaced as well?

You need at least 1 activity if I am not mistaken, so you can't get rid of all. If you already use one, then you are there already. You can probably get rid of all the fragment/glue code and have it as a container for your first composable logic/wiring and then be free.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you mentioned works. Since your activity is hosting fragments, it needs to inherit from `FragmentActivity` during migration. Once all your fragments' contents are in Compose, you can remove all fragments and replace Navigation component with Navigation Compose, and inherit directly from `ComponentActivity` (you will still need at least one activity in your app).

Note that the strategy you mentioned is also aligned with our [migration strategy](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/migration-strategy) page.